# How to fix file paths in the LUBM generator?

Tags: rdf, benchmarking, owl, lubm

I tried to generate 160000 pieces of data using the [LUBM generator](http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/projects/lubm/).

Unfortunately, the generator wrongly generates backslashes in file paths:

```
$ java -cp classes/ edu.lehigh.swat.bench.uba.Generator -onto http://asdf.com/xyz
Started...
/home/user/LUBM\University0_0.owl generated
CLASS INSTANCE #: 1657, TOTAL SO FAR: 1657
PROPERTY INSTANCE #: 6896, TOTAL SO FAR: 6896
```

You can see the wrong path `/home/user/LUBM\University0_0.owl`

How do I make it generate the correct paths?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to edit the source code a little. Specifically the `src/edu/lehigh/swat/bench/uba/Generator.java`

Line *647* of `Generator.java` contains the part `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" +`. Change it so that it looks as follows:

```
private void _generateDept(int univIndex, int index) {
  String fileName = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" +
      _getName(CS_C_UNIV, univIndex) + INDEX_DELIMITER + index + _getFileSuffix();
  writer_.startFile(fileName);
```

This holds for version UBA1.7 of the generator.

Comment: Or `System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator +`, to make it portable.